# Why TryInto needs Copy trait in T?

Tags: rust

I have this code but fails because T needs has implemented Default AND Copy to convert the slice to a array.
Why needs the trait Copy?

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn fill_default<T: Default, const N: usize>() -> [T; N] {
    std::iter::repeat_with(|| T::default())
        .take(N)
        .collect::<Vec<T>>()
        .as_slice()
        .try_into()
        .unwrap()
}
```

Comment: your code don't make sense, you create a vec but return an array ? this isn't gonna work. `fn fill_default<T: Default, const N: usize>() -> [T; N] { [T::default(); N] }`

Comment: @Stargateur the function you wrote also requires Copy to be implemented in T and what I want to do is to make a function that does not need Copy.

Answer (score 1):

The [TryInto](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) trait is defined as consuming the value so that implementations can be more efficient (eg. reuse data already allocated for the value in the converted value by taking it and throwing away the rest).

Since you are returning an array by move, and the vector that is collected is not used for anything else, you don't need to use `.as_slice()`, which returns a reference to the vector, but instead pass the vector directly to `.try_into()` which will consume the vector and produce the correct output.

When I tried compiling it, I was getting an additional error cause by the unwrap() combined with the type parameter `T` not having a `std::fmt::Debug` constraint.  You can either add the constraint or return a `Result` or 'Option` to get around that.

Comment: thanks for the remark that I don't need the as_slice.
Now I will be fighting not to need Debug either.

Comment: The Debug requirement is caused by the panic that tries to print the value inside the `.unwrap()`.  You can either return the `Result` without the unwrap, or you can use a match statement on the result from `.try_into()` and if it's `Ok(val) => return val` or if `Err(x) => panic!("Can't do that")`, which will work because the panic!() format string doesn't have `{:?}` in it, which would require Debug

Comment: @kirbylife All types should be able to implement `Debug`. There is no practical reason to try and avoid the requirement.